# Why bother with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm learning about SQL for the first time, and I'm following along from this website: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

The author goes to the trouble of declaring a foreign key, but I don't think it ever does anything for us. Here's the example from the page:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id INT,
    amount DOUBLE,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id)
);

INSERT INTO `customers` (`customer_id`, `customer_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Adam'),
(2, 'Andy'),
(3, 'Joe'),
(4, 'Sandy');

INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES
(1, 1, 19.99),
(2, 1, 35.15),
(3, 3, 17.56),
(4, 4, 12.34);
```

Some tables are created, and the customer_id in the orders table is made to reference the customer_id in the customers table.

Here's what confuses me: the author of the article executes the following statements with various results:

```
SELECT * FROM customers JOIN orders;
SELECT * FROM customers NATURAL JOIN orders;
SELECT * FROM customers JOIN orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id;
```

There are more statements involving `LEFT` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`s among other things, but at no point does the foreign key ever influence anything.

Am I missing something, or are these examples too simple to merit the use of a foreign key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key definition -- alas -- is not used in `SELECT` statements.  This is a shame, because `NATURAL JOIN` should use the `FOREIGN KEY` definition.  "Should" here is a moral imperative.  The ANSI standard specifies that it uses columns with the same name, rather than the explicit key definitions.  In my opinion, there is no reason to use `NATURAL JOIN`.  Avoid it in favor of the `USING` clause instead.

They are used in other circumstances.  Notably, the foreign key definition validates that data inserted into or updated in a table has correct values.  This is very important and the foundation of relational integrity.

In addition, they allow cascading constraints.  These "update" related tables when a primary key value is changed or deleted.

Note that a foreign key definition can be a hint used by the optimizer.  You may not see the effect, but it is information that can be used for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key is being used in the statement

```
SELECT * FROM customers JOIN orders WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id;
```

in the `WHERE` clause - the part about `customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id` is exactly the application of the foreign key relationship.

Foreign key *constraints* do not result in implied foreign key relations during a `SELECT`. The purpose of a constraint is to restrict ("constrain") the values of data being inserted into the constrained columns. Thus they only come into play during `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations.

In this case specifically, when a value is inserted or updated in `orders.customer_id`, the database first verifies that that value already exists in the column `customers.customer_id`; if the value does not exist the database will cause the statement to fail.